# slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, slice, tostring

It gives me an error that slice is not function despite I convert the slice from number to string.
where is the issue ?

```js
var weight = prompt("Enter your Weight");
var height = prompt("Enter your Height");
function bmi(weight, height) {
  var result = weight / Math.pow(height, 2);
  var count = result.toString.slice(0, 4);
  if (result < 18.5) {
    alert("Your result is " + count + ", so you are underweight.");
  } else if (result >= 18.5 && result <= 24.9) {
    alert("Your result is " + count + ", so you have a normal weight.");
  } else {
    alert("Your result is " + count + ", so you are overweight.");
  }
}

bmi(weight, height);
```

I convert the slice from number to string but gives me the same erroe where is the issue ?

Comment: Change `var count = result.toString.slice(0, 4);` to `var count = result.toString().slice(0, 4);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't actually call `toString()`.

`toString` resolves to a function object, which you would then call with `()` to get a string. The error you're seeing is telling you that the function object itself does not have a `slice()` method, which is true.